# Remove apps from "Open with..." list

Tags: macos, finder, applications

I have too many suggested apps listed under "Open with..." for certain file types.

For example, for .html, I just want two options: Chrome and an HTML editor instead of the currently very messy list that includes every browser and text editor that are installed on my system.

I find it a UI impediment to have to fish for specific entries in a context menu that includes apps that are only installed for testing purposes and are not daily go-to programs.

Is there a way to do this in MacOS?

Answer (score 1):

No. There's no way to modify that list. As you may know, apps report the file types they support to the OS, and as a consequence those file types show in the app's Open file dialog; and the app is listed as an app that can open those files.

Your best option is to use another method of launching the files in the apps you want; or once you have the **Open With...** menu showing, start typing **C H** (assuming you have no other apps starting with those letters).